# C - how to store IEEE 754 double and single precision

Tags: c, floating-point, format, ieee-754

I have to work with IEEE 745 double and single precision numbers.
I have no idea, how to work with them correctly.

I've got a buffer of binary data and I want to get the numbers like

```
uint8_t bufer[] = {................};
//data I want are at 8th position, (IEEE745_t is my imaginary format)
IEEE745double_t first8bytes = *(IEEE745double_t*)(buffer + 8);
IEEE745single_t next4bytes = *(IEEE745single_t*)(buffer + 16);
```

What do I put instead of `IEE745double_t` and `IEEE745single_t` ? Is it possible to do it with double and float? And if so, how can I guarantee, that they will be 8 and 4 bytes long on every platform?

Comment: Surfing Google for a few minutes, I was able to find _[this post](http://www.technical-recipes.com/2012/converting-between-binary-and-decimal-representations-of-ieee-754-floating-point-numbers-in-c/)_, and several others that talk about converting IEEE 754 binary to float etc.

Comment: i've found that too... doesn't solve my problem... this is basicaly about converting float to dec. Or mabye I missunderstood it, so correct me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you cannot do the pointer cast hack. There is absolutely no guarantee that your byte buffer is correctly aligned. This results in *undefined behaviour*. Use `memcpy` instead:

```
memcpy(&first8bytes, &buffer[8], 8); 
memcpy(&next4bytes, &buffer[16], 4);
```

> What do I put instead of `IEE745double_t` and `IEEE745single_t`? Is it possible to do it with double and float?

Yes, it's possible, **if**:

- `double` is 8 bytes, `float` is 4 bytes and both use IEEE754 presentation.
- Data on `buffer` uses same byte order as your host. If not, you need to copy to temporary unsigned integer type first, where you fix the endianness.

> And if so, how can I guarantee, that they will be 8 and 4 bytes long on every platform?

Use static assertion to detect when it's not. For example:

```
static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4, "invalid float size");
```

Comment: @chux Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: ok, thanks! I dont understand what you mean by correctly aligned buffer, could you explain it more, please?

Comment: @Charlestone Many CPUs have limitations that, for example, 32-bit type has to start from address which is divisible by 4, and 16-bit type divisible by 2. When you dereference from random location of buffer, it may be incorrectly aligned. This is one of the reasons why aliasing different pointer types is mostly illegal in C. Use casting with care, because it will disable any compiler warnings these cases.

Comment: ok, but the thing is, that the location is NOT random, I exactly know where the bytes I want begin (I read binary data from serial port with exactly specified order). My colleague told me to do the thing with the pointers, because it's easier to read. Is it save then?

Comment: @Charlestone No, it's still not safe. `uint8_t buffer` can be aligned anywhere. You can use compiler specific tricks to align buffer manually, or you can be on system where unaligned access only incurs performance penalty. *But even then,* there is possibility that compiler optimizations, which rely on strict aliasing, break your code. Your collague is lacking information on this area: It's not about which code is easier to read, it's about what is right and wrong. I have had one hard to track bug caused by this. Use `memcpy`, it is simple and it works.

Comment: @Charlestone If you are interested in making code clean, I would recommend moving the copy to utility functions like this: `float GetFloat32(const uint8_t * buffer) { float f; memcpy(&f, buffer, sizeof f); return f; }`. That way it looks nice, and is easier to modify if you need to port your code to other systems. (Like change the byte order, if new host has different endianness)